# Linux/MacOs - Know which process filter UDP 443 packets

Tags: linux, macos, sockets, udp, firewall

Is there a way, on Linux / MacOs to find which process is filtering my UDP packets on a specific port ?

Here some details and why I'm asking:

On my MacOs ( Mojave 10.14) , if I try to send a UDP packet to any address ( DNS resolves correctly) to port `443`, I cannot see anything leaving my laptop ( using tcpdump)

If I do the exact same test but for a different port , for instance `444`, I can see the packet leaving ( on tcpdump).

There is a process which is filtering UDP packet to port 443 and I want to know which process it is ( Firewall disabled on my mac).

The exact commands I'm using for my tests :

```
sudo tcpdump udp port 443
nc -u IPADDRESS 443
I type something stuff here..

==> I cannot see anything going through

sudo tcpdump udp port 444
nc -u IPADDRESS 444
I type something stuff here..

==> I can see a datagram leaving my interface
```

I know this can be tricky to find which process might be filtering this port.. If anyone has an idea, would be great.
I would not want to rely on the method ' Kill everything until it works'

Comment: Why are you trying to use UDP on port 443? That's the port used by https, which is a TCP-based protocol...

Comment: Sorry this lacks a bit of context.. I'm trying to connect to a OpenVPN server which is listening to port 443 UDP, but I cannot obviously because of this filtering happening.

Comment: When you run `sudo tcpdump udp port 443` and you fire up a browser, do you see any trafic ?

Comment: when opening a browser, this would mainly be TCP traffic. Here I'm talking about a traffic that has nothing to do with HTTP. I'm really looking for a way of identifying, maybe at kernel level, which process filter my datagrams

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm having the exact same issue but with port 80 and TCP.